# Cant convert byte to string and eventually to a number

Tags: python, byte, decode

I wish to use the class variable in order to predict the accuracy of my kmeans model. So i need it to be purely as an integer 1 or 2 for which i think i will need to convert it to string first. But im getting an error when using the decode function

```py
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = arff.loadarff('bnknote.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
df.head()

V1  V2  V3     V4                        Class
0   3.62160 8.6661  -2.8073 -0.44699    b'1'
1   4.54590 8.1674  -2.4586 -1.46210    b'1'
2   3.86600 -2.6383 1.9242  0.10645     b'1'
3   3.45660 9.5228  -4.0112 -3.59440    b'1'
4   0.32924 -4.4552 4.5718  -0.98880    b'1'
```

```py
import codecs
Class=df['Class']
Class=codecs.decode(Class,'UTF-8')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py in decode(input, errors)
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-face6f646db6> in <module>()
      1 import codecs
      2 Class=df['Class']
----> 3 Class=codecs.decode(Class,'UTF-8')

TypeError: decoding with 'UTF-8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series')
```

Comment: Can you provide your code which cause described error?

Comment: @Daewo 
`import codecs
Class=df['Class']
Class=codecs.decode(Class,'UTF-8')`

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: decoding with 'UTF-8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series')
```

means you have tried decoding whole column of `pandas.DataFrame` at once. You do not have to use `codecs` here, it is sufficient to use `.astype` as `int` has no problem when working with ASCII-encoded representation of integer, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'],'y':[b'1',b'0',b'1']})
df['y'] = df['y'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

output

```
   x  y
0  A  1
1  B  0
2  C  1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton .. Your solution was pretty easy and worked like a charm ! I unnecessarily went on to create another variable that assumes values of 1 and 2 based on b'1' and b'2'  using `np.select`